# Binary relation on the set $X = \{v, w, x, y , z\}$ that is asymmetric and transitive but not negatively transitive

Tags: microeconomics, preferences, choice-theory

So I am trying to find a binary relation on the set $X = \{v, w, x, y, z\}$ that is asymmetric and transitive but not negatively transitive, and is quite tricky.

Will $R = (v, w)$ be asymmetric and transitive but not negatively transitive?

Comment: What happens if you test your suggestion? It is asymmetric since $aRb \implies \lnot bRa$.  What about the other two?

Comment: @Henry wont it be transitive but not negatively transitive?

Comment: What makes you think it is transitive?  What makes you think it is not negatively transitive?

Comment: @Henry it is transitive because it is only comparing 2 elements, while it is not negatively transitive since there it is not the case that if xRy, neither xRz or zRy

Comment: If you are satisfied all three conditions are met with your suggestion then you have a solution.  I would have said that it is not negatively transitive because  $vRw$ but $\lnot xRw$ and $\lnot vRx$